# How can I convert a PDF file to a PRN file?

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I have a JAVA program that creates a PDF file.
However I need to send this PDF file to a printer via SDK for this printer that would only accept PRN file type …

I understand that a the PRN file is built by using the specific driver for the specific printer, so the java program should be able to pick the driver for use in order to convert the PDF to a PRN file

As for the question, why wouldn’t I send the PDF file directly to print via the driver, well, this is a zebra printer that prints and encode smart cards, performing printing and encoding is only available if approaching it from the SDK, if I were to sent in directly to the driver , it would only print without encoding the cards

Answer (score 3):

The PDF will need to be rendered and set into the format desired by the printer.

GhostScript is what you want for this, the command would be:

```
gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=PrinterName -sOutputFile="c:/out.prn" "file.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your printer manufactor is Zebra and you are searching vendor specific solution to the problem. Here is an open source project [jZebra](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) that is support many vendors and as i understood it has capability to print from PRN file. Check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/jzebra-users/browse_thread/thread/4e94d9ab5d9799eb#) thread if it is applicable for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you are lucky and the file you are trying to open contains plain text you can try this:

1. Change extension of this file from prn to txt
2. Open new file in notepad or any other text editor

You may see exactly what you wanted plus some header that can be removed later.

Answer (score 0):

Zebra printers use zpl language. You can design your zpl template and send it to your printer as a prn file.

```
^XA
^FX Top section with company logo, name and address.
^CF0,60
^FO50,50^GB100,100,100^FS
^FO75,75^FR^GB100,100,100^FS
^FO88,88^GB50,50,50^FS
^FO220,50^FDInternational Shipping, Inc.^FS
^CF0,40
^FO220,100^FD1000 Shipping Lane^FS
^FO220,135^FDShelbyville TN 38102^FS
^FO220,170^FDUnited States (USA)^FS
^FO50,250^GB700,1,3^FS
^XZ
```

Copy the text above and paste it into the notepad. Save it as abc.prn and send it to your printer.

You will see, it will print a label (I assume you are using a 4x6 printer).

So you can create your own zpl template using this website. http://labelary.com/viewer.html
and this guide 
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf